Error with 'extends' keyword in Azure DevOps YAML Pipeline with Variables
I'm experiencing an issue with my Azure DevOps YAML pipeline configuration. My structure is similar to the following:
main.yml
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: somepipeline
      source: somesource
      branch: branch

parameters:
  - name: debug
    type: boolean
    default: false

extends:
  template: /.pipelines/template-publish-pipeline.yml@self
  parameters:
    debug: ${{ parameters.debug }}

template-publish-pipeline.yml
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: someorg/repository
      ref: refs/heads/main

parameters:
  - name: "debug"
    type: boolean
    default: false

variables:
  - group: SomeGroup
  - group: SomeGroup2

  - name: "system.debug"
    value: ${{ parameters.debug }}

  - template: .pipelines/templates/variables/variable-template.yml@templates

  - group: SomeAnotherGroup
  - name: Connection
    value: "Connection Name"

extends:
  template: somepath/toatemplate@templates
  parameters:
    parameter123:
      enabled: false
    stages:
      - stage: BuildSetup
        jobs:
          - job: BuildNameSetup

When I attempt to validate the above pipeline, I encounter the following error:
Unexpected value 'extends'

However, the same setup works correctly if I remove the variables and move them to the main.yml file.
My Questions:

Is there a way to keep the variables in the template-publish-pipeline.yml file or use another template just for the variables?
Is there any workaround to use both variables and extends inside the template?

From what I understand, the extends and variables keywords cannot coexist in the same template. Is there a known solution for this issue?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I tried keeping the variables in the template-publish-pipeline.yml file while using the extends keyword. I expected the pipeline to validate successfully and use the variables defined within the template.

Have you tried to define the - repository: templates resource in main.yml rather than in template-publish-pipeline.yml?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I just tried that and unfortunately the error is still the same:
Unexpected value 'extends'

So your main.yml extends a template template-publish-pipeline.yml and template-publish-pipeline.yml extends another template somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates?

Yes, it will incur the error Unexpected value 'extends', because we can only extends one single template. But we can include multiple templates. I will have a test and share the working sample shortly.

Yes, main.yml extends a template template-publish-pipeline.yml and template-publish-pipeline.yml extends another template somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates
you're saying that it will incur the unexpected value 'extends'
But I've tried moving the variables to the main template and it works fine in that case.
So the problem might by that we cannot use a nested extends and variables together?

Thanks for the clarification. I can understand what you mean now and I have also reproduced the same issue.

Is this what you mean when you say to use includes instead of extends in main.yml?
jobs:
- job: Windows
  pool:
    type: windows
  steps:
  - template: /.pipelines/template-publish-pipeline.yml@self
    parameters:
      debug: ${{ parameters.debug }}

I just tried it and I'm getting the same error:
Unexpected value 'extends'

But this time I have the variables in the main.yml.

I will have a further test and share the findings in the answer.

Hi there, I managed to pass the pipeline validation and succeeded a sample build with the workaround below to include somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates in .pipelines/template-publish-pipeline.yml@self and keep the variables in .pipelines/template-publish-pipeline.yml@self as well. Please feel free to test it. Hope it may help resolve your queries in this post. Thanks a lot for your sharing.

Based on the description and discussions, I could reproduce the issue when the pipeline definition main.yml was extending the template template-publish-pipeline.yml and again this template was extending another template. It seemed that duplicate extends had the pipeline unable to validate the variables section defined in between.

Per the expectation/requirement to keep the variables in the template-publish-pipeline.yml file and reference the variable template .pipelines/templates/variables/variable-template.yml in @templates repo resource, I would suggest the workaround to include rather than extend the template somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates in the extended template .pipelines/template-publish-pipeline.yml@self.
Here is the modified template-publish-pipeline.yml for your refence. The validation worked from my side. Please pay attention to the syntax differences in how the other template somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates was referenced.
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: someorg/repository
      ref: refs/heads/main

parameters:
  - name: "debug"
    type: boolean
    default: false

variables:
  - group: SomeGroup
  - group: SomeGroup2

  - name: "system.debug"
    value: ${{ parameters.debug }}

  - template: .pipelines/templates/variables/variable-template.yml@templates

  - group: SomeAnotherGroup
  - name: Connection
    value: "Connection Name"

stages:
- template: somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates
  parameters:
    parameter123:
      enabled: false
    stages:
      - stage: BuildSetup
        jobs:
        - job: BuildNameSetup
          steps: 
          - script: echo A sample task


Adding sample context of somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates to avoid any possible misunderstanding.
parameters:
- name: parameter123
  type: object
  default: {}
- name: stages
  type: stage
  default: {}

stages:
- ${{ parameters.stages }}


I believe this should be able to work in most of cases.
Unfortunately in my case, somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates is not something that we own and it is using another extends as well as resources inside them which again is causing the same error as previously.
But instead of the template-publish-pipeline.yml, it is now in the somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates template

Hi @AhmadShafique, I didn't suggest modifying somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates, I only shared then sample context for other community members' reference to understand the workflow.

I had reproduced the same issue and resolved it by changing extends: template: somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates to be `stages:

template: somepath/toatemplate.yml@templates` in template-publish-pipeline.yml. Thus, it was not extending but including the template.


But for your update that there were more extends in some of other templates, that may incur validation failures as well.
